# How to find a date time value in an excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel, datetime

I need to find the first cell which contains a datetime value.

The cell I am interested in displays this

> 06-Mrz-2015 00:00

It's formula field has this (two spaces after the date part)

```
06.03.2015  00:00:00
```

The cell format is this

```
DD-MMM-YYYY hh:mm
```

I tried this but it does not find the cell

```
Public Function FindCurrentCell() As Range

Dim cell As Range
Dim current As String

Sheets("Futures").Select

current = Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy") + "  00:00:00"

Set cell = Cells.Find(What:=current, After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

Dim test As String
test = cell.Address

Set FindCurrentCell = cell

End Function
```

Comment: It works fine here; Are you sure the formula field display 06.03.2015  00:00, not 12:00:00 AM/PM?  Also is it just a date or a result from calculation?

Comment: Not sure about how this would affect you using a string, but something like `If c.NumberFormat Like "dd.mm.yyy  hh:mm" Then` should work

Comment: You say the `NumberFormat` uses hyphens but `current` uses periods.

Comment: ok `if c.numberformat like "DD-MMM-YYYY  hh:mm then` either way, @tony I don't understand why there's a need for the `current` string, so maybe I'm missing the point. I wouldn't use `.find` instead I'd `for each next`

Comment: @Raystafarian.  After much experimentation I discovered that the standard advice about searching for dates is rubbish; `current` is not necessary.  See my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

If you search the web you will find many sites that tell you how to find a date.  However, they present the answer as a magic spell: “Do this complicated series of steps and it will work.”  The trouble is: what do you do if it does not work?

Apparently you need:

```
.Cells.Find(What:=DateValue(Format(DateWanted, "dd/mm/yyyy")))
```

where "dd/mm/yyyy" represents Excel’s standard date format for your country.

No variation of "dd/mm/yyyy" that I can discover will allow me to successfully find dates formatted as you wish.

The source of the problem is how Excel stores dates.  As I type this, it is 9:23 on 7 March 2015.  If I type `? CDbl(Date)` and `CDbl(Now())` into the Immediate Window, I get:

```
? CDbl(Date)
 42070 
? CDbl(Now())
 42070.3911805556
```

42070 is the number of dates since 1 Jan 1900.  .3911 is (Number of seconds since midnight) divided by (Number of seconds in a day).

So if I see “7 March 2015” or “7/3/15” in a cell, I know that, behind the scenes, Excel is holding 42070 with `.NumberFormat` telling it that 42070 is a date and how to display that date.

The experts tell you that in `DateValue(Format(DateWanted, "dd/mm/yyyy")))` you need to get “dd/mm/yyyy” just the way Excel expects a date to be formatted.  The trouble with this statement is that `DateValue` will discard all your careful formatting and return a date so what was the point?

All this advice about the format is not only rubbish but, apparently, harmful rubbish.  All that matters is that the “What value” is of Date type.  For example, both the following are valid:

```
Cells.Find(What:=Date)

Dim SearchDate As Date: SearchDate = Date
Cells.Find(What:=SearchDate)
```

I was going to remind you that the Date must be an exact match; for example, a search for “7 March 2015” will not find “7 Match 2015 9:00”.  In fact, this is untrue.  It appears the oft repeated advice to this effect is only true if you fuss with the formatting.

```
Sub Test()

  Dim RngToday As Range

  Set RngToday = FindCurrentCell

  If RngToday Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "Today's date not found"
  Else
    Debug.Print "Today’s date in " & RngToday.Address
  End If

End Sub
Public Function FindCurrentCell() As Range

  Dim cell As Range

  With Worksheets("Futures")

    Set cell = .Cells.Find(What:=Date, After:=.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                           SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    If cell Is Nothing Then
      ' Today's date not found
      ' Add any appropriate code
    Else
      ' Today's date found
      ' Add any appropriate code
    End If

  End With

  Set FindCurrentCell = cell

End Function
```

Comment: So as I far I can get with your explanation, is that I can find `today` like this. Was that the OP's intention? Could you expand this to find maybe any member of a population of dates, say a year or a month?

Comment: @Raystafarian  In the OP's question, the function searches for `current` which is a formatted string based on the function `Date`. My understanding is that somewhere within worksheet "Futures" there is a cell containing today's date formatted in a particular way. My routine will find the first cell containing today's date regardless of how it is formatted. If the worksheet, contains multiple copies of today's then my routine will need to loop until it finds the cell with the correct date and the correct `.NumberFormat`. If the formatting is a red herring, my routine will meet the OP's needs.

Comment: My guess is by OP using `Date` that yes, the search is for today. But say it wasn't, for my own curiosity, how would one scale it?

Comment: @Raystafarian. A function such as `FindDate(byVal SearchDate as Date) As Range` could find any date of interest.  `Find` does not have a range option; you cannot, for example, search for "Cat" to "Dog".  I do not know how you use `Find` to find any date within a range of dates such as a 1Mar15 to 31Mar15 or 1Jan15 to 31Dec15. I wrote this to answer the second part of your first question. I think it answers your second question as well.

Comment: My only thought was if, say, looping through cells looking for cells with the date-format, then comparing the value outside of the search. This is probably pretty far off from what the OP originally meant, so I digress. +1

Comment: @Raystafarian. I would expect `Find` for a single date to be a lot faster than a VBA loop searching for a `.NumberFormat`. So for `FindFormattedDate(byVal SearchDate as Date, NumberFormat As String) As Range`, I would use `Find` to locate possible dates then check `NumberFormat` before moving on if necessary. Having said that, I have recently discovered that some Worksheet functions are a lot slower than VBA.